# Can't access React props modified by Redux MapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

Got undefined when trying to access this.props.state value

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = ({ movies }) => ({
  state: movies,
});

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.addMovie({ title: 'Movie' }); //redux action
  }

  render() {
    const { state } = this.props;
    console.log(state.test);       //Object {title: "Movie"}
    console.log(state.test.title); //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    return (
      <div>Hello {state.test.title}!</div> //doesn't work
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

After redux complete the action i've got state object in component props

[image: Redux DevTools]

I can access it from Chrome DevTools `$r.props.state.test.title` but can't access it from render function

For example I can get value from `this.props.params.movieID` but can't get any params modified by `mapStateToProps`

How can I put `this.props.state.test.title` value in my div?

Comment: Can you paste the actual error, what exactly did you get as undefined?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your render function check if the title is undefined because the render function is being called before your redux action is resolving. Once your state is updated and your component renders it should show up the second time.

```
render() {
  const { state } = this.props;
  console.log(state.test);
 if(state.test && state.test.title){
   console.log(state.test.title); 
    return (
     <div>Hello {state.test.title}!</div>
   )
} else {
   return (
    <div>No movies listed</div>
  );
 }
}
```